# Function for list is undefined

Tags: function, undefined, clisp

I'm having problems with clisp.I'm tryng just to get the sum of the numbers in a list,but it gives me this error:

```
 EVAL-the function L is undefined
```

when i call

```
(sum '(2 (c 6)))
```

Here is the code:

```
(defun sum(l)
        (cond
           ((null l) 0)
           ((NUMBERP (car l)) (+ (car l) (sum(cdr l)) ))
            (t (sum(cdr(l))))
        )
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`(cdr(l))` invokes the function `l` and applies `cdr` to the value it returns.

You should write `(cdr l)` instead:

```
(t (sum (cdr l))))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
(defun sum (x) (if (null x) 0 
                    (if (numberp x) x 
                         (+ (car x) (sum (cdr x))))))
```

by the way you could do similarly with product

```
(defun prod (x) (if (null x) 1 
                    (if (numberp x) x 
                         (* (car x) (prod (cdr x))))))

(eq (prod '(1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10)) (fact 10))
```

but define fact first - here you are a defun for fact (the usual one...)

```
(defun fact (n)
     (if (not (integerp n)) (print "give me an integer" )          
        (if (< n 0) (print "give me a pos num " )          
         (if (= n 0) 1    
             (if (= n 1) 1 
                 (* n (fact (- n 1)
)))))))
```